# Angular2 Routing. The requested path contains undefined segment at index 1

Tags: angular, routes, webpack, datatables, navigation

I have a issue with routing in Angular 2.
I call router.navigate from an action into a datatable. The rare is that sometimes when i click the button that calls this line its works fine and sometimes it doesnt.

```
this.router.navigate(['edit', id], {relativeTo: this.activatedRoute});
```

The error that shows the inspector element is:

```
The requested path contains undefined segment at index 1
```

Im using Angular2, DataTables, and Webpack

Comment: Update -> the problem is that sometimes read the id and sometimes no. So the problem is with the Datatables.

Answer (score 40):

Probably your `id` that pass into in `navigate` is `undefined` or `null`.console your id and fix and then pass into in navigate .i had same issue and fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue. The basic reason was, It wasn't finding the LINK (url) for the the item. i.e.

**BEFORE**

```
 {
    e2eId: '1',
    title: 'myTitle',
    link: null,
    icon: 'icon',
    isActive: false,
   }
```

**AFTER**

```
{
    e2eId: '1',
    title: 'myTitle',
    link: '/somelinehere',
    icon: 'icon',
    isActive: false,
   }
```

This issue may also arise due to Null value of id or something else with null value as well.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. When I inspected the values passed to the navigate function, I found that my url was undefined. Actually, the main problem was that I tried to navigate before the data was ready. You have to check first if your data is ready to be passed. Like waiting for an event or be subscribed to another callback.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue recently. It was because the route param that I was trying to pass to router navigation was null.